# Adding PHP code in HTML which is already in PHP?

Tags: php, html, variables, syntax

Basically, I want to add a PHP variable in HTML, with that HTML already being inserted into a constant, which is in PHP code. Here's what I mean: (obviously this code below is wrong, but imagine I would want to be inserting the $VARIABLE in the URL of the iFrame, for example)

```
<?php
$VARIABLE = 'example-sub-category';
const EXAMPLE = "<iframe src='http://example.com/$VARIABLE'></iframe>";
?>
```

What would be the syntax for adding that variable in there?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't modify constant after you declared it.

Comment: Are you working within a class?  If not, you should be using [`define`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Comment: You declared Example as const, but you added $variable to it. const means constant and can't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a basic template.  `str_replace()` should do the trick.

```
const EXAMPLE = "<iframe src='http://example.com/{{{VARIABLE}}}'></iframe>";
$variable = 'example-sub-category

$merged_content = str_replace('{{{variable}}}', $variable, EXAMPLE);
```

Note I used `{{{}}}` to denote the insert.  This is not PHP syntax, but you will find templates often use something like that the would not be expected in the text otherwise to denote placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<?php
    $VARIABLE = 'example-sub-category';
    const EXAMPLE = "<iframe src='http://example.com/".$VARIABLE."'></iframe>";
?>
```

Comment: Won't the quotation marks surrounding the variable interfere with the quotation marks from right before the iframe? In that case would it be sufficient if I just added the backslashes before the quotation marks ( \" )?

Comment: I think you are getting confused. The full stop (period) indicates concatenation. In this instance three separate strings are being concatenated into one. Double quotation marks hold their own separate strings, therefore there are no quotation marks surrounding the variable as these are the end and beginning of the first and third strings, respectively.

Comment: Alright I understand. However when I try what you said, it doesn't work. Do you have any idea why that may be? In my case I have even more quotation marks outside of the URL, so would that be interfering in any way?

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the code itself. As Rujikin pointed out, you need to be careful when mixing single- and double-quotes, especially with variables. I would advise writing your code using a real-rime syntax checker - I personally use NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert PHP anywhere in HTML just by defining its tags `<?php ?>`

```
<iframe src='http://example.com/<?php echo $VARIABLE; ?>'></iframe>
```

Using your example:

```
const EXAMPLE = "<iframe src='http://example.com/" . $VARIABLE . "'></iframe>";
```

Comment: As I said to @verbumsapienti: won't the quotation marks surrounding the variable interfere with the quotation marks from right before the iframe? In that case would it be sufficient if I just added the backslashes before the quotation marks ( \" )?

Comment: Quotation marks of the same type interfere but different types do not interfere with one another. I typically use ' marks for php and " for HTML. So long as the HTML uses a different type from the PHP there will be no issues. Also in PHP " marks will process variables while ' will not process variables.

Comment: Yes escaping the quotation would fix an issue involving same quotations as well `$string ='some test\'s';`. Using \ basically means "interpret literally, no special meanings", or at least that is how I remember it.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task I'd better use sprintf:

```
$VARIABLE = 'example-sub-category';
const EXAMPLE = "<iframe src='http://example.com/%s'></iframe>";

echo sprintf(self::EXAMPLE, $VARIABLE);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.

Answer (score 0):

To move in and out of php within your html, use `<?` [php code here...] and `?>` to end php and continue with html. You can escape characters with a back slash \ and using single quotes as Rujikin mentioned above. Or, within PHP, you can echo your html so that you're not bouncing in and out of php.

For example:

```
some php...
echo '<span style=\"color:#980000\"><strong>\"{$searchTerm}\"</strong></span>';
more php...
```

Notice that the html is enclosed in single quotes (end-to-end) and inside the single quotes, double quotes are used where required by html, e.g., for the `<style>` tag.

This example is basically saying, "echo whatever the value of php variable `$searchTerm` is, put it in quotes that's required by echo, and make it dark blue (`#0000FF`) and bold (`<strong>`).

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like:

```
<?php
$VARIABLE = 'example-sub-category';
const EXAMPLE = "<iframe src='http://example.com/$VARIABLE'></iframe>";

$newHtml = str_replace('$VARIABLE', $VARIABLE);
?>
```

---

As you mentioned your code was fake, so I guess what you need is to replace some places in your HTML strings by a content which is unknown until you php script is executed, right ?

so what you need is to put some place holders and change them later, as I showed in my snippet above.

Hope this works